# Formatting in VB 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How do you format some columns in a datagrid to numbers only?

How do you format some columns in a datagrid to Y or N only?

My problem is that when I format the columns to Y or N or numbers only it does all the columns not the ones I need?

Comment: Please show us what you done unit now especially some code.

Comment: If (e.ColumnIndex = 4) Then   ' Checking numeric value for Column4 only
            Dim value As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
            For Each c As Char In value
                If Not Char.IsDigit(c) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = String.Empty
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub